# Android: application ends when choosing an image from the gallery

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm implementing a feature that enables the user to choose their own profile picture from gallery on clicking a button.

1. This is the part implemented under the onCreate method to call the intent to choose an image from the gallery.

   ```
   btnChooseProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent();
           intent.setType("image/*");
           intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
           startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), REQ_CODE_SELECT_IMAGE);
       }
   });
   ```
2. Now I overrode the onActivityResult method to set the chosen image to the imageview.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   if(requestCode == REQ_CODE_SELECT_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
       try {
           ivProfile.setImageURI(data.getData());
       } catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```

   }

When running the application and testing this part, I managed to reach the gallery but that's it. When clicking an image, the application would just be out, while leaving no error messages on Logcat.

What do you think is wrong with snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just silly enough to miss it

In the Androidmanifest.xml file I added this attribute to the activity.

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Because of this attribute, when I chose to select an image from the gallery, the activity changed into the other one and the original one was removed out of the stack. So after selecting an image, the application could not find where to go back, and that's why my application crashed.

Now I deleted that attribute, and the code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove " && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK " from the if condition.You will get your solution. but this way is not proper.try this way if you want.